# HTML5 Canvas and JS - Mouse Movement, strange error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am trying to make my image follow my mouse. I have used a lecture guide from university to create this code, and it seems identical to all the code I've seen, but I get the error in Chrome developer tools: 
Uncaught TypeError: thisCanvas.addEventListener is not a function

Any ideas? I've stared at this for hours now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Gravity Game </title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    </head>

    <body onLoad="start_game()">
        <header>
            <h1 id = "title1"> Gravity </h1> <h1 id = "title2"> Game </h1>
        </header>

        <ul id = "nav">
            <li class = "inactive"><a href = "about.html"> About </a></li>
            <li id = "active"><a href = "play.html"> Play Game </a></li>
        </ul>

        <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "1500" height = "500"></canvas>

        <script>
            var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.background = 'white';
            var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
            var worldX = 100;
            var worldY = 100;

            //Draw a circle
            /*context.beginPath();
            context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();*/

            thisCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove",seen_move,false);

            function seen_move(e)
            {
                var bounding_box = thisCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                worldX = (e.clientX-bounding_box.left) * (thisCanvas.width/bounding_box.width); 
                worldY = (e.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (thisCanvas.height/bounding_box.height);
            }

            function start_game()
            {
                setInterval(loop_game, 50);
            }

            function loop_game()
            {
                thisCanvas.width = thisCanvas.width;
                update_world(worldX, worldY);
            }

            function update_world(x, y)
            {
                var world_img = new Image();
                world_img.src = "images/world.png";
                context.drawImage(world_img, x, y);
            }



        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.background = 'white';
```

`thisCanvas` now has the string value `white`.

`thisCanvas.addEventListener()` is basically like saying `'white'.addEventListener()`. Because there’s no `String.prototype.addEventListener` this won’t work.

You need to assign `document.getElementById("myCanvas")` to `thisCanvas` and *then* set its background color.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.background = 'white';
```

should be

```
    var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
```

---

You are trying to assign your canvas style-changing methods as variable `thisCanvas`, instead of assigning the canvas element itself

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I've added the background style to the css page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with:

```
var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.background = 'white';
```

`thisCanvas` does not hold a reference to the <canvas> element.  Instead, it's bound to `'white'` because of a chained assignment.

You probably want something like:

```
 var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 thisCanvas.style.background = 'white';
```